LWC lightning-input date's datepicker is displaying outside datatable
I have a datatable with date input field. The problem is the datepicker is very far from the input type. It's outside the datatable. How to display it just adjacent to its input field? Let's say, below or above?
<lightning-input type="date" value={value} onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
Also, the datatable is customized.
Here is the property for the date input field column
tableCols = [
        {
            label: "対応期日",
            fieldName: "correspondenceDate",
            fixedWidth: 120,
            type: "datePicker",
            value: { fieldName: "correspondenceDate" },
            typeAttributes: {
                editing: { fieldName: "editColumn" }
            }
        }
];


I have tried the CSS below:
.slds-datepicker {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 99999999 !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}

But the datepicker is still burried in the datatable like below:

